# VBA - cannot click a link within unordered list

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to click a link within an unordered list in webpage. I'm using the this code,

```
Set linkElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each linkElement In linkElements
  If linkElement.getAttribute("id") = "level1st" Then   'Also tried using "onclick" and "innerText"
       linkElement.Click
       Exit For
  End If
Next linkElement
```

the html snippet is,

```html
<div class="tree" id="treeDiv" style="width: 288px; border-top-color: transparent; border-top-width: 195px; border-top-style: solid;" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
  <ul style="width: 491px;">
    <li>
      <a id="level1st" onclick="resetTree(0);" href="#">GENERAL INFORMATION</a>
      <ul></ul>
    </li>
```

However, when I run the code, nothing happens in the web page. 
Also, it is a dynamic unordered list which loads after clicking a submit button so I have also added a ie.busy...loop before this code.

I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know vba, but doesn't a method getElementById() exist there? Seems strange to loop all elements just to find an element by id....

Comment: @baao Have tried it the first time and it did not click the link.

Comment: @baao I used getAttribute to check other attributes also like onclick and innerText

Comment: Check if there are frames on the page, if so, you need to reference to the document of the apprpriate frame.

Comment: @omegastripes Yes there are frames..but how do I reference to the appropriate frame

Comment: Open webpage in browser, click context menu on target element, choose Inspect element. In opened DOM tree you can find the frame, check [how to reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vba+reference+frame+document).

Comment: @omegastripes Thank you. Will look into it and post if there are any doubts..